# awk : Match Pattern after certain pattern and Print words next to Pattern

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I need to match for some patterns if it matches I need to print the next few words to it.. I have only three such conditions to match… But I need to print only those words that comes after satisfying the first condition.. iez..

Though before LLL SSS I have TTT , I need to print only the ones that comes after LLL SSS to AAA RRR ,and again when I encounter LLL SSS need to do the same , I have tried declaring a awk flag variable, but it doesn’t seem to work. Kindly help me.

```
var1="LLL";var2="SSS";var3="TTT";var4="AAA";var5="RRR";
awk -v flag=1 '{
for (m=1;m<=NF;m++)
if($m~m/'$var1'/ && $(m+1)~/'$var2'/)
print "ABCD: ", $(m+2),$(m+3),$(m+4)
{flag=0};
else {
if {flag==0 && $m~/'var3'/)
print "EFG : ", $(m+1);
else { 
if (flag==0 && $m~/'$var4'/ && $(m+1)~/'var5'/)
print "HIJ: ",$(m+2),$(m+3) 
{flag=1}; 
}
}
}
}' fliename
```

My file is something like this:

```
AAA RRR H I
DDDD OOO HI J UGC RR
TTT YYY
LLLLL IIIIII
LLL SSS A B C D
N
DDDD TTT EFG
BBB AAA RRR J K
HHHHHH RRRRRR 
LLL SSS E H G H
N
DDDD TTT EFG
UUUUU BBB AAA RRR J K
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Having a flag named `flag` is like having a kid and naming it `kid`. Come on... Also how about some indenting?

Comment: Andalso, your code syntax does not make much of sense. It's hard even to edit.

Comment: If You want to match a field against a token, do need to not use regex. It is too inaccurate in this case. Also You can read the environment variables inside awk using the `ENVIRON["var1"]` hash. You could test one field match like `if ($m == ENVIRON["var1"])`.

Comment: @TrueY, +1 for suggesting equality over matching, but using ENVIRON  means you have to `export` the relevant variables

Comment: @glennjackman: You are right! Or call `var1=LLL var2=SSS awk '...'`.

Comment: Right, you don't HAVE to export the variables for ENVIRON, you can set them to their own values on the command line, e.g. `x="$x" awk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["x"]}'` but personally I'd never use ENVIRON anyway when `-v var=value` is clear and simple. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for more info.

Answer (score 3):

When you have multiple nested `if`s like this, it's really important to use braces to be completely unambiguous. I've made an attempt to rewrite your code.

- use `-v` to pass shell variables into awk instead of playing with quoting
- whitespace is your friend -- or rather it's the friend of the next guy who has to maintain your code.
- fixed a couple of errors on line 8 of your script

```
var1="LLL";var2="SSS";var3="TTT";var4="AAA";var5="RRR";
awk -v flag=1 \
    -v var1="$var1" \
    -v var2="$var2" \
    -v var3="$var3" \
    -v var4="$var4" \
    -v var5="$var5" \
'{
    for (m=1; m<=NF; m++) {
        if ($m ~ var1 && $(m+1) ~ var2) {
            print "ABCD: ", $(m+2),$(m+3),$(m+4)
            flag=0
        }
        else {
            if (flag == 0 && $m ~ var3) {
                print "EFG : ", $(m+1)
            }
            else {
                if (flag == 0 && $m ~ var4 && $(m+1) ~ var5) {
                    print "HIJ: ",$(m+2),$(m+3)
                    flag=1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}' fliename
```

Comment: +1 for `whitespace is your friend -- or rather it's the friend of the next guy who has to maintain your code`

Comment: In the for-loop the max value is `NF-1`. If really important to write nonempty info, then `NR-4`.

Answer (score 0):

Glenn's version improved a little bit. I negated `flag` so initialization can be skipped.

```
var1="LLL";var2="SSS";var3="TTT";var4="AAA";var5="RRR";
awk -v var1="$var1" -v var2="$var2" -v var3="$var3" -v var4="$var4" -v var5="$var5" \
'!flag {
    for (m=1; m<=NF-1; ++m) 
        if ($m == var1 && $(m+1) == var2) {
            print "ABCD: ", $(m+2),$(m+3),$(m+4)
            flag=1
            next
        }
 }
 flag {
    for (m=1; m<=NF-1; ++m) 
        if ($m == var3) {
            print "EFG : ", $(m+1)
            break
        } else {
            if ($m == var4 && $(m+1) == var5) {
                print "HIJ: ",$(m+2),$(m+3)
                flag=0
                break
            }
        }
}' filename
```

Output:

```
ABCD:  A B C
EFG :  EFG
HIJ:  J K
ABCD:  E H G
EFG :  EFG
HIJ:  J K
```

Or You can even try a pure bash version:

```
var1="LLL";var2="SSS";var3="TTT";var4="AAA";var5="RRR";

found=0;
while read -a a; do
  if [ $found -eq 0 ]; then
    for((i=0;((i+1))<${#a[*]};++i)) {
      [ ${a[$i]} == $var1 -a ${a[((i+1))]} == $var2 ] &&
        echo ABCD: ${a[((i+2))]} ${a[((i+3))]} ${a[((i+4))]} &&
        found=1 && break
    }
  else
    for((i=0;((i+1))<${#a[*]};++i)) {
      [ ${a[$i]} == $var3 ] && echo EFG: ${a[((i+1))]} && break
      [ ${a[$i]} == $var4 -a ${a[((i+1))]} == $var5 ] && found=0 &&
        echo HIJ:  ${a[((i+2))]} ${a[((i+3))]} && break
    }
  fi
done <filename
```

Comment: @user2428250: I added a pure `bash` solution.